# How to add externally stored link text into a hyperlink?

Tags: hyperref, verbatim, links

I have a bunch of links which are individually stored in text files. I would like to create a LaTeX document in which those files are accessed using relative paths and the link included into the final PDF. The reason is that later in the future I might want to change the links in the files and the generated PDF should update accordingly.

This is what I have tried:

```
\usepackage{verbatim}
\href{\verbatiminput{./links/1.txt}}
```

but I get the error:

> TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].

Here is a minimum working example:

Create File: `1.txt`

1.1. Input https://www.youtube.com/

1.2. Close file

Latex Code without pulling from text file

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage{hyperref}% for the links
\usepackage{verbatim}% for the input

\begin{document}%
\href{https://www.youtube.com}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}

\end{document}%
```

works great !

now with pulling from text file

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage{hyperref}% for the links
\usepackage{verbatim}% for the input

\begin{document}%
\href{\include{1.txt}}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}

\end{document}%
```

I get the errors:

> line 10: Argument of @include has an extra }. \href{\include{1.txt}}
>
> line 10: Paragraph ended before @include was complete.
>
> \href{\include{1.txt}} line 10: Paragraph ended before \href@ was
>
> complete. \href{\include{1.txt}} line 10: Extra }, or forgotten
>
> \endgroup. \href{\include{1.txt}} line 10: Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too
>
> wide) in paragraph

**EDIT:**

based on @Ulrike Fischer, I tried

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage{hyperref,catchfile}% for the links
\usepackage{verbatim}% for the input

\begin{document}%

\CatchFileDef\myurl{1.txt}{}
\href{\myurl}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}

\end{document}%
```

but I got:

> Package catchfile Error: File `1.txt' not found.
>   \CatchFileDef\myurl{1.txt}{} Suppressing link with empty target
>   Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide) in paragraph

**EDIT 2:**

Also tried to create a new command, but did not work:
http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex_19.html

```
\newcommand\urlFromFile[1]{\CatchFileDef{#1}{}}
```

**EDIT 3:**

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage{hyperref,catchfile}% for the links
\usepackage{verbatim}% for the input


\usepackage{hyperref,catchfile}
\newcommand\urlFromFile[1]{%
    \CatchFileDef\myurl{#1}{\catcode`\#=12\catcode`\%=12}%
    \expandafter\url\expandafter{\myurl}}

\begin{document}
    \href{\urlFromFile{1.txt}}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}
\end{document}
%
```

I get:

> line 16: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000].
>   \href{\urlFromFile{1.txt}}

Comment: what is the format of the link in the external file?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It`s just a hyperlink to a website as a text format

Comment: \href{}{} expects two inputs. \url{} works with one. Both are from the package hyperref. Can you please provide a MWE with the contents of both files?

Comment: @letsfetz I added a MWE. Thanks

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I added a MWE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use catchfile to load the url:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{1.txt}
https://www.youtube.com/
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref,catchfile}
\CatchFileDef\myurl{1.txt}{}
\begin{document}
\expandafter\url\expandafter{\myurl}
\end{document}
```

If the url contains special chars like % or _ or # you can use the last argument of the command to setup the catcodes.

An extended example with some special chars and a command:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{1.txt}
https://www.youtube_blub#%.com/
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref,catchfile}
\newcommand\urlFromFile[1]{%
 \CatchFileDef\myurl{#1}{\catcode`\#=12\catcode`\%=12}%
 \expandafter\url\expandafter{\myurl}}
\begin{document}
\urlFromFile{1.txt}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ? Three questions: 1. I have a lot of theses files (1.txt,2.txt,3.txt,4.txt etc.), how can I include them with your method ? 2. My urls look like that "https://youtu.be/r54oAmvqt5I?t=368", how can I include the special characters ? 3. Do I put the \myurl command into the \href where the link would normaly go?

Comment: please see edit. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I was curious, I tested a simple `\include` instead of `catchfile` and it did not work. So, `catchfile` is crucial here.

Comment: @OlegLobachev Can you have a look at my second edit, maybe you know how to change the command so that it works ?

Comment: @OlegLobachev \include is the completly wrong command. This is not a simple command. Beside others it issues a \newpage and write an aux-file.

Comment: @james I added an example with a command.

Comment: Great! thank you so much ! Now, the only issue that I have is that catchfile cannot find the file for some reason. I have stored it in the same directory as the tex document and named it 1.txt. I get the error: Package catchfile Error: File `1.txt' not found. \urlFromFile{1.txt}

Comment: well if you named it `1.tex` you shouldn't try to use `1.txt`.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I have named it 1.txt. Typo, edited the comment just now

Comment: Found the error, I indeed misspelled the file. Thank you so much for your kind and patient help !!

Comment: I am almost there... please see edit 3, if you still have the time. :)

Comment: well  the command contains an \url command, so it can't be used in a \href command. You will have to define a similar \hreffromfile command in which you replace \url by \href.