# Read link from external text file and include into hyperlinked image

Tags: hyperref, external-files, links

I would like to incorporate a link into a picture using \href. The links are stored in text files. The .tex file should be able to read form those text files (i.e. 1.text) and generate that clickable image.

I already got quite a good answer in this question [How to add externally stored link text into a hyperlink?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527570/how-to-add-externally-stored-link-text-into-a-hyperlink)

...but I still have a problem:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage{hyperref,catchfile}% for the links
\usepackage{verbatim}% for the input

%To generate a text file for demonstration
\begin{filecontents*}{1.txt}
https://www.youtube.com/
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage{hyperref,catchfile}
\newcommand\urlFromFile[1]{%
    \CatchFileDef\myurl{#1}{\catcode`\#=12\catcode`\%=12}%
    \expandafter\url\expandafter{\myurl}}

\begin{document}
    \href{\urlFromFile{1.txt}}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}
\end{document}
%
```

I get:

> line 16: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000].
>   \href{\urlFromFile{1.txt}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage{hyperref,catchfile}% for the links
\usepackage{verbatim}% for the input

%To generate a text file for demonstration
\begin{filecontents*}{1.txt}
https://www.youtube.com/
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage{hyperref,catchfile}
\newcommand\hrefFromFile[1]{%
    \CatchFileDef\myurl{#1}{\catcode`\#=12\catcode`\%=12\endlinechar=-1}%
    \expandafter\href\expandafter{\myurl}}

\begin{document}
    \hrefFromFile{1.txt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I noticed that there is an issue with the link. The link looks like "https://www.youtube.com%20/" instead of "https://www.youtube.com". Do you have any ideas how to solve that ?

Comment: I see no problem when I compile the example.

Comment: Do you get redirected to youtube when you click on the image ? I don´t.

Comment: I think the problem is that catchfile somwhoe adds a new line to the url and this then gets converted into %20, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271/url-encoding-the-space-character-or-20

Comment: or a space https://www.fullhost.com/blog/what-does-20-mean-in-a-web-address/

Comment: I added `\endlinechar=-1` to the setup.

Comment: Awesome !! Works now!  Thank you so much !! Really appreciate your help !