# Pass content file to macro

Tags: macros, verbatim, input, loops, catchfile

I'm trying to execute a macro that get a string as a parameter. I want to load the string from as a verbatim content of a file.

I'm oriented mostly on `catchfile` package with no success.

I've already seen

- [How to add externally stored link text into a hyperlink?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527570/how-to-add-externally-stored-link-text-into-a-hyperlink)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414191/using-verbatim-as-part-of-an-argument-for-a-macro
- [How do I create a macro which reads the content of a file when the macro is defined?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14145/how-do-i-create-a-macro-which-reads-the-content-of-a-file-when-the-macro-is-defi)

The file that I'm trying to import is full of different chars that could mislead so they should be interpreted as is. A small excerpt is (almost 10M of this stuff):

```
"@%$&DO\)9G}"-2"#""${@,}"11)+7${*^^}#1${*~}5)  ] ${*/&IIBs-2/v~1LAX}   $[   ((${@/+$Dw/R6k\{MQq:}-4"0"${!*}#"1"9-50"#"p)+${*,}29"#"4"h")   ] ${@//\[>2;^n}  ${!*} $(( (-(-(8#"1"61--"${@#Z\"2B53\{}"44#1$*E)+48#${*//OzmgVT%}2G))  ))  "${@##w\`$8}"   ${*%%om\[3W}  $(( (-(-(6#305--${@~}1"5"#${@//7ox@}2"c")+1${*,,}8"#""${@,,}"5${@%AVRW$,bC}6))   )) $@  $((  (-(-(3"7"#"p"*"${@/\]\`DcL\{/5g<yo}"50#${*,,}g)+30#b${*//vQN2uO~}b))   ))  ${@^}  $[   (-(-(1${*##\"hbv}1"${@//QVTk$}"#44+${@}43#"g")+4${@~}#11)) ] ${!*}  $((  ((34#o*"-"5${*#:\}imbKB}9#e)+"${@//t^Qyala/V1-=}"6"4"#6b)  ))  ${*,,}  $[  ((${*^}7#1$*0+4#21)+"3"4#${@#gxK5}o)  ]   ${*^^}   "${@//EoF$3/Euw\"#\)wl}" $(( ((${*~~}-5"7"#11+-${*#6UV>x6X}1${@/N\[ME}3#"c")+${@//X^F4Iz}3"1"#4c)   )) ${*^}   $[   (("3""#"202--4#13)+"4"5"#"w)   ] ${!*} ${*} $[ (-(-(34#n*"5"1${!*}#e)+14#14b)) ]   ${@,,} ${*/FGP\)Lf=}   $((  (("-"53#29+19#3${*#<&v\]}5)+${*~~}7"#""${@%%6&\"6?y6}"220)   )) ${@#67OE\}6}   "$@"   $((   ((-3#210+3"3"#"m")+2"${@,,}"6${@%=_FI?@T}#g) ))  "${@,}"  "${@~}"   $((  ((-1"2""#"1"8"-"-"59#10)+5#34)   )) ${@#WCeSRm} $(( ((-42#"${@#wPI&XRM}"1*23"#""0")+25#2)  ))   ${@/jKCyd/.5i0+\)z|}   $[   ((${*/7vBD*a}50#t--"4"#11)+"${@/$4HZ/wb5|\"N\};}"5"7"#m) ] ${*%%S2G0}  "${@//,uHr\`/h\`P93v1}"  $(( (-(-("$@"-1"9"#"1"0*-19${@/+\}J@#}#${@,,}c)+26${!@}#6g)) ))   "${@^}"  $((  ((-${*//i\=m~}19#c+64#b)+3#22)  )) ${*~}   ${!@} $((   ((${*^^}49#1G-${*#E;s;}1"5""#"2${*//We8#=^N+}7)+6${@/Fi2X0E4/.>:\}}4#a) )) ${@,} $((   ((-3"2"#v--"2"#1${*/TKD^2/\~=4@<}0${@~}0)+37#1n)  )) "${@~~}"   $[ ((20#"${@~}"e+2#100)+3${*~~}8"${@/Z7zg/n2u$O}"#1)   ]  ${@,,} $[   (-(-(7#${@,,}1"${@/PrCWYpAH/ICk|\(n}"1--${@}6"0"#k)+8#${@/nsJeW2}1"1")) ]  ${*%%4pEVH} ${*~~}   $((   ((59$@#A-3#12)+"2"4#${@^^}j)  ))  ${*,,}  ${!*}  $[   (-(-("${@//9h2775\]}"-4#12*-"4"#${@~~}1"0")+46#c))  ]   ${@/fw.Vf/|ao2V\`}   ${*%.@a<n}   $[  ((6${*}#"1""2"*"-"${@##UqN0}28#2)+51"#"13)  ] ${*/AJ\"W/WGu=}   $(( (-(-(6${*##@.IF}#${*##KDu\"}1--36#"u")+12#b))   ))  ${*#x1bN}   ${@~} $[  (-(-(${@~~}40${@^^}#${*^^}1c+5"4"#b)+"6"#13)) ]  ${@//~Ppe}   ${!@}   $[ (-(-("3"7#2"${@,,}"s-"-"$*14#2"d")+6#220))  ]   ${!@}   ${*~~}  $((   ((${*##_X\)oJY-}-17#"e"-${@//ES-w}1"2""#"${@//qxTm&/T=Pq@~l6}1"5")+3"9"${!@}#"2""c") )) ${*%%qvnCy_}   ${*~~}  $[  ((-3${@//\"vi9PxAA}9#r*40"#"g)+13#"2"ba)   ]   "${@%~|\[&\!}" ${@~~}   $[ ((23#"a"-${*~}2#"${@//JJgS/\)go~\)}"11)+"1"7"${@//RsGDY2sc}"#${*##&\`Q@_b}a)   ] ${@/lY\]\!D\(}   $((   ((-40#${!*}2f+"-"22${*,}#${*^}2"${@//xz\!\!lu}"3)+"5"9"$@"#3n)  ))   $*   $(( ((60${*#yulPQ}#1*${*~~}39#${*//zYWRJ/nQBHX~g}0)+${*,}54"#"2) ))   ${*//FNXb\"Cq/hdD;A*9\\}  $[  ((-6"4"${*~~}#1*43${*,,}#"0")+39#1d)   ] ${!*} $[ ((30#"1"6-${*#ZLe>\)d}6${*~}#"1"2)+3#100) ]  "${@/<tRzdd/_+j;\]x-\"}"   ${@^}   $(( (-(-(5#"1"${@//\[\oc\"*}1+3#$*22)+4"#"${@~~}1"${@^^}"2))  ))  ${*//SRToaWNl}  ${@%$\]PV2}   $[   ((-"6"0#e*11"#"12)+21"#"b1) ]  "${@~}"   ${@}  $((   ((-3"6""#""v"+15#${*^}31)+5"6"#q) )) ${@%%AS=MW^}  "${@//d+JA}" $((  (("-"29${*~}#15+23#3d)+2#100)  ))  ${*%\{A\{0M\"#n} $((  ((51"#"${*,}c*-"4"1"#"${*^^}a)+${*,,}55"#"2S) )) "${@~~}"  $
```

I need to apply some transform to each char what I've tried so far is

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\def\xloop#1{
  \ifx\relax#1
    \else
      \framebox[5ex]{
        \vrule height 2.5ex depth 1.5ex width 0pt\relax
          #1
      }\hskip0pt
      \expandafter\xloop
  \fi
}
\def\addbox#1{\xloop#1\relax}

\makeatletter
\CatchFileDef{\content}{test.sh}{\let\do\@makeother\dospecials\@noligs\obeyspaces\frenchspacing\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \addbox\content
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wouldn't argue with latex here. I would rather look into lua to accomplish this. Classical file system I/O is not was latex was build for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your files are one liners, you can use `expl3` to read them and to apply the loop.

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.txt}
"@%$&DO\)9G}"-2"#""${@,}"11)+7${*^^}#1${*~}5)  ] ${*/&IIBs-2/v~1LAX}   $[   ((${@/+$Dw/R6k\{MQq:}-4"0"${!*}#"1"9-50"#"p)+${*,}29"#"4"h")   ] ${@//\[>2;^n}  ${!*} $(( (-(-(8#"1"61--"${@#Z\"2B53\{}"44#1$*E)+48#${*//OzmgVT%}2G))  ))  "${@##w\`$8}"   ${*%%om\[3W}  $(( (-(-(6#305--${@~}1"5"#${@//7ox@}2"c")+1${*,,}8"#""${@,,}"5${@%AVRW$,bC}6))   )) $@  $((  (-(-(3"7"#"p"*"${@/\]\`DcL\{/5g<yo}"50#${*,,}g)+30#b${*//vQN2uO~}b))   ))  ${@^}  $[   (-(-(1${*##\"hbv}1"${@//QVTk$}"#44+${@}43#"g")+4${@~}#11)) ] ${!*}  $((  ((34#o*"-"5${*#:\}imbKB}9#e)+"${@//t^Qyala/V1-=}"6"4"#6b)  ))  ${*,,}  $[  ((${*^}7#1$*0+4#21)+"3"4#${@#gxK5}o)  ]   ${*^^}   "${@//EoF$3/Euw\"#\)wl}" $(( ((${*~~}-5"7"#11+-${*#6UV>x6X}1${@/N\[ME}3#"c")+${@//X^F4Iz}3"1"#4c)   )) ${*^}   $[   (("3""#"202--4#13)+"4"5"#"w)   ] ${!*} ${*} $[ (-(-(34#n*"5"1${!*}#e)+14#14b)) ]   ${@,,} ${*/FGP\)Lf=}   $((  (("-"53#29+19#3${*#<&v\]}5)+${*~~}7"#""${@%%6&\"6?y6}"220)   )) ${@#67OE\}6}   "$@"   $((   ((-3#210+3"3"#"m")+2"${@,,}"6${@%=_FI?@T}#g) ))  "${@,}"  "${@~}"   $((  ((-1"2""#"1"8"-"-"59#10)+5#34)   )) ${@#WCeSRm} $(( ((-42#"${@#wPI&XRM}"1*23"#""0")+25#2)  ))   ${@/jKCyd/.5i0+\)z|}   $[   ((${*/7vBD*a}50#t--"4"#11)+"${@/$4HZ/wb5|\"N\};}"5"7"#m) ] ${*%%S2G0}  "${@//,uHr\`/h\`P93v1}"  $(( (-(-("$@"-1"9"#"1"0*-19${@/+\}J@#}#${@,,}c)+26${!@}#6g)) ))   "${@^}"  $((  ((-${*//i\=m~}19#c+64#b)+3#22)  )) ${*~}   ${!@} $((   ((${*^^}49#1G-${*#E;s;}1"5""#"2${*//We8#=^N+}7)+6${@/Fi2X0E4/.>:\}}4#a) )) ${@,} $((   ((-3"2"#v--"2"#1${*/TKD^2/\~=4@<}0${@~}0)+37#1n)  )) "${@~~}"   $[ ((20#"${@~}"e+2#100)+3${*~~}8"${@/Z7zg/n2u$O}"#1)   ]  ${@,,} $[   (-(-(7#${@,,}1"${@/PrCWYpAH/ICk|\(n}"1--${@}6"0"#k)+8#${@/nsJeW2}1"1")) ]  ${*%%4pEVH} ${*~~}   $((   ((59$@#A-3#12)+"2"4#${@^^}j)  ))  ${*,,}  ${!*}  $[   (-(-("${@//9h2775\]}"-4#12*-"4"#${@~~}1"0")+46#c))  ]   ${@/fw.Vf/|ao2V\`}   ${*%.@a<n}   $[  ((6${*}#"1""2"*"-"${@##UqN0}28#2)+51"#"13)  ] ${*/AJ\"W/WGu=}   $(( (-(-(6${*##@.IF}#${*##KDu\"}1--36#"u")+12#b))   ))  ${*#x1bN}   ${@~} $[  (-(-(${@~~}40${@^^}#${*^^}1c+5"4"#b)+"6"#13)) ]  ${@//~Ppe}   ${!@}   $[ (-(-("3"7#2"${@,,}"s-"-"$*14#2"d")+6#220))  ]   ${!@}   ${*~~}  $((   ((${*##_X\)oJY-}-17#"e"-${@//ES-w}1"2""#"${@//qxTm&/T=Pq@~l6}1"5")+3"9"${!@}#"2""c") )) ${*%%qvnCy_}   ${*~~}  $[  ((-3${@//\"vi9PxAA}9#r*40"#"g)+13#"2"ba)   ]   "${@%~|\[&\!}" ${@~~}   $[ ((23#"a"-${*~}2#"${@//JJgS/\)go~\)}"11)+"1"7"${@//RsGDY2sc}"#${*##&\`Q@_b}a)   ] ${@/lY\]\!D\(}   $((   ((-40#${!*}2f+"-"22${*,}#${*^}2"${@//xz\!\!lu}"3)+"5"9"$@"#3n)  ))   $*   $(( ((60${*#yulPQ}#1*${*~~}39#${*//zYWRJ/nQBHX~g}0)+${*,}54"#"2) ))   ${*//FNXb\"Cq/hdD;A*9\\}  $[  ((-6"4"${*~~}#1*43${*,,}#"0")+39#1d)   ] ${!*} $[ ((30#"1"6-${*#ZLe>\)d}6${*~}#"1"2)+3#100) ]  "${@/<tRzdd/_+j;\]x-\"}"   ${@^}   $(( (-(-(5#"1"${@//\[\oc\"*}1+3#$*22)+4"#"${@~~}1"${@^^}"2))  ))  ${*//SRToaWNl}  ${@%$\]PV2}   $[   ((-"6"0#e*11"#"12)+21"#"b1) ]  "${@~}"   ${@}  $((   ((-3"6""#""v"+15#${*^}31)+5"6"#q) )) ${@%%AS=MW^}  "${@//d+JA}" $((  (("-"29${*~}#15+23#3d)+2#100)  ))  ${*%\{A\{0M\"#n} $((  ((51"#"${*,}c*-"4"1"#"${*^^}a)+${*,,}55"#"2S) )) "${@~~}"  $
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\ior_new:N \g_pna_getfile_ior
\str_new:N \l_pna_getfile_str

\NewDocumentCommand{\getfile}{mm}
 {% #1 = file name, #2 = loop macro
  \ior_open:Nn \g_pna_getfile_ior { #1 }
  \ior_str_get:NN \g_pna_getfile_ior \l_pna_getfile_str
  \str_map_function:NN \l_pna_getfile_str#2
  \ior_close:N \g_pna_getfile_ior
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\loopfbox}[1]{%
  \framebox[5ex]{%
    \rule[-1.5ex]{0pt}{4ex}%
    #1%
  }\hspace{0pt}%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
\getfile{\jobname.txt}{\loopfbox}
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, multiple spaces are preserved.